# How do I process this format of timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

How can I process an output like

```
"TimeStamp: 1635251181000"
```

into a readable format in Python. I tried `datetime.fromtimestamp()` but I got an error like

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Looks like a timestamp in milliseconds. Try `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(val/1000)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Unix `time_t` value (seconds since 1/1/1970), multiplied by 1000 to include milliseconds.  It's the same value returned by `time.time()*1000`.  So:

```
>>> t = 1635251181000
>>> time.ctime(t/1000)
'Tue Oct 26 05:26:21 2021'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert timestamp to datetime format, your should divide your timestamp by 1000.

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1635251181000


utc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts/1000)
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000)
print(local_time)
print(utc_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Tim provides the exact reason for your error. For a little more information on this, refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149289/995052). Even though its related to Java, the fact stands.

If the length of your timestamp is 13, then it will be a millisecond timestamp. This is true till end of `2286` :-) . So if you expect variation in your timestamps, its better to check and set it.

If your input is like `"TimeStamp: 1635251181000"` Then try this

```
from datetime import datetime
your_in = "TimeStamp: 1635251181000"
your_ts = your_in.split("TimeStamp:")[1].strip()
if len(your_ts)> 10:
    your_ts= int(your_ts[:10])
your_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(your_ts)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = your_timestamp
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/1000)

print("dt_object =", dt_object)
print("type(dt_object) =", type(dt_object))
```

Comment: Some explanation as to what the code is doing and why you chose that code will help...